# Insert item between ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I have the following code that displays the items

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="#item of items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now the items object is something that I get as a result of an http call to an API.

Let's say this is the following code.

```
this.http.get('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
      this.items= data['results'];
});
```

What I want to achieve is that I want the third Item to be a custom Item and then render the following items normally.

How can this be achived.

Thanks

Comment: why dont you manipulate the data before rendering it to the view @krv

Comment: Give an example of your custom item.

Comment: Do you mean the third item should be *replaced with* a custom element? *Preceded by* an extra element? Is it always the third, or does it depend on the items? Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: yes @jonrsharpe The third Item should always be the third and must not replace the data just push it down. Using Angular 4

Comment: Did either answer help?

Answer (score 10):

You can keep track of the index of the `*ngFor` by using `let i = index`, you can then use a `*ngIf` to perform an action when the index is in position 3. See below, I used `<pre></pre>` because I have no idea what `item` is.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <pre *ngIf="i !== 2; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></pre>
    </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #thenBlock>{{item}}</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>//Display something for item 3</ng-template>
```

Your HttpGet is wrong though, I'm assuming you're using the new `HttpClient`, it should be:

```
this.http.get<any>('/api/items').subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.items = data;
});
```

If it's the old `Http`:

```
this.http.get('/api/items')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.items = data;
     });
```

Comment: Rather than if and if not, you could use if; else (Angular 4+) or a switch, to avoid repeating the condition and making it harder to change later. See e.g. the last paragraph of my article here: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/May/20/angular-ng-elements.html

Comment: Thanks this will work. But if i am not mistaken isn't there a RxJs operator that can do this?

Comment: There might be, but not that I'm aware of at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comment, you actually need something like:

```html
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
    <li *ngIf="i === 2">...</li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Note the loop over a container, rather than the element itself, so we can have a varying number of elements in each step without breaking the layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="#item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"">
       <span *ngIf="i == 2"> this is third element {{item}} <span>
       <span *ngIf="i != 2"> {{item}} <span>
   </li>
</ul>
```